# Windows Mobile: Deployement error?

Tags: windows-mobile

It may be simple question, but i couldn't find the solution yet, so querying it below.

How to kill(not programmatically) running my app in Windows Mobile Standard 6.0 Simulator? I was looking into Task Manager app, but it doesn't available in this simulator. Though i exited my app and come to home screen, seems to be my app doesn't be exited properly running in the background. Due to this, if i want to deploy(via Start debugging in VS) again, VS does say 'There were deployment errors. Continue?' .

How can i resolve it without soft resetting the simulator?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way will be to use the Process Viewer in Visual Studio's Remote Tools, find the process and kill it.

I also recommend for development/debugging purposes to have a way of actually exit your application. You can add a button for it or simply handle the OnClose event of your form.